# Ajax call still wait until process is killed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, com

i'm using ajax to call a php script that will convert a DOCX file to PDF, using COM class of PHP (on WAMP stack).
Here there is a little problem, php do the work, it convert 
 regularly the file and print a json with the download URL but until Word.Application will not be closed, seems ajax request cannot manage the response.

So, there are 2 problems:

1- Ajax cannot manage response until Word.Application opened by PHP is completely closed, even if the script reach the end

2- Word.Application need very much time (sometimes 10-20 seconds, sometimes 3-4 minutes) to close completely

PHP script run on Windows Server 2003, MS Office is 2010, and PHP is 5.4.
If i force the close of WINWORD.exe (Word.Application), the ajax script start to manage the response.

The ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: HTTP_ADDRESS+'/url-to-conversion-server/',
            type: 'post',
            data: postVars,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
    });
```

The PHP script:

```
    $word = new COM('word.application');
    $word->Visible = 1;
    $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;

    $doc = $word->Documents->Open('C:\\path\\to\\file.docx');
    $doc->ExportAsFixedFormat('C:\\path\\to\\save\\file.pdf', 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);
    $word->ActiveDocument->Close(false);

    $word->Quit();
    unset($word);

    exit(json_encode(array('url' => ADDRESS."/path/to/save/file.pdf")));
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you tried `set_time_limit()`  and `register_shutdown_function()` to catch the fatal error raised by the time limit and returning the response to the client?

Comment: Hi Swapgs, yeah i have tried, unfortunately it does not produce any result :\ WINWORD still running, and the client does not print anything. I have tried with a limit of 20 seconds and 40 seconds

Comment: I have found a semi-solution, but the problem remain. If i don't close winword using `$word->quit()` the script exit normally, but winword obv remains active. So, the problem is the closing of winword that block the end of the script.